Text Outline Stroke for 3D Printing - Intersecting Geometry
I'm trying to do an outline/ stroke of handwriting text. But all methods are failing me.
Three ways

Bevel round and
Profile
Alt + S (4th if you count outline text to curve than object along curve)

Bevel round is giving me weird pointing geometry
(Ive tried mesh - recalculate normals outside and merge vertices)
Profile is giving same results.
Alt + S
Again, the intersecting geometry gives me holes when I bring it into 3d print software.
(this is the major problem, intersecting geometry)
The best method for this is Tinkercad. Why does this software have an easy simple button but blender does not?
But as you can see it has jaggered edges, not smooth
Is there and addon in Blender that gives better text outline geometry?
Please blender make a button. If tinkercad can do it. Why not you guys?
I have found 2 ways around this.
Freecad will do this but just more messing around.
Make a SVG file for both text and outline.
(But I can't find any software that exports the outline, it only exports the text)
(Tried Inkscape and Canva)
I understand for simple text in Blender I can create the outline for 3d printing, no worries. But for handwriting and more complex text it becomes messy with the geometry.







Ok I just found that in TinkerCad there is a "quality" button to make edges smoother.
But PLEASE blender add this function in.

This is not a developer site, we cannot add features to Blender unless we happen to be Blender devs. You should post feature requests on https://rightclickselect.com

This looks like the geometry was fattened, and then the original was Boolean-ed out of the fattened version. I’m not sure how to implement that procedurally. The use case is a poly curve path, correct?

(1) Could you share a Blender file, using https://blend-exchange.com/, including the "handwriting text" you are trying to outline ? (2) Are you looking for the "Adam"  or the "Emily" style ?

Thanks for the feedback. But at this stage Tinkercad is the most viable option untill Blender add this function.  I will share this with rightclickselect
